# Jboss Deployment Error failinfg due to Exception starting filter ServicesResponseTime: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: jboss7.x

```
12:41:12,546 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) 2016/02/11-07:11:12,546 UTC MLD Log init: com.teamcenter.mld version V10000.1.0.20130604.00 (20130604)

12:41:12,553 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log.properties found in the classpath

12:41:12,695 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 2016/02/11-07:11:12,695 UTC MLD Log init: com.teamcenter.mld version V10000.1.0.20130604.00 (20130604)

12:41:12,698 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) log.properties found in the classpath

12:41:12,970 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/tc]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception starting filter ServicesResponseTime: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.teamcenter.mld.jmx.PlmSimpleMBeanFactory.<clinit>(PlmSimpleMBeanFactory.java:168) [plmJMXmonitor.jar:]
    at com.teamcenter.mld.logging.Log.<init>(Log.java:848) [plmJMXmonitor.jar:]
    at com.teamcenter.mld.logging.Log.<clinit>(Log.java:173) [plmJMXmonitor.jar:]
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.appframework.log.LogFactory.getLog(Unknown Source) [tcappframework.jar:]
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.appframework.log.LogFactory.getPkgLog(Unknown Source) [tcappframework.jar:]
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.gateway.filters.ResponseTimeFilter.<clinit>(Unknown Source) [tcgateway.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ValueManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ValueManagedReferenceFactory.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:90) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$1.<init>(WebComponentInstantiator.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator.getReference(WebComponentInstantiator.java:55) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.instantiate(WebInjectionContainer.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:78) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:441) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: javax.management.JMRuntimeException: Failed to load MBeanServerBuilder class org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder from [Module "deployment.tc.ear.tc.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.checkMBeanServerBuilder(MBeanServerFactory.java:503) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.getNewMBeanServerBuilder(MBeanServerFactory.java:539) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.newMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:316) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:231) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at com.teamcenter.mld.jmx.PlmLocalMBeanServer.getMBS(PlmLocalMBeanServer.java:396) [plmJMXmonitor.jar:]
    at com.teamcenter.mld.jmx.PlmLocalMBeanServer.<clinit>(PlmLocalMBeanServer.java:89) [plmJMXmonitor.jar:]
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder from [Module "deployment.tc.ear.tc.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.loadBuilderClass(MBeanServerFactory.java:446) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.checkMBeanServerBuilder(MBeanServerFactory.java:488) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    ... 40 more

12:41:13,032 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/tc]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception starting filter SoaRestResponseTime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.teamcenter.presentation.appframework.log.Log
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.appframework.log.LogFactory.getLog(Unknown Source) [tcappframework.jar:]
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.appframework.log.LogFactory.getPkgLog(Unknown Source) [tcappframework.jar:]
    at com.teamcenter.soa.ptier.ResponseTimeFilter.<clinit>(Unknown Source) [TcSoaWeb.jar:10000.1.0, June 4, 2013]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ValueManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ValueManagedReferenceFactory.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:90) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$1.<init>(WebComponentInstantiator.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator.getReference(WebComponentInstantiator.java:55) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.instantiate(WebInjectionContainer.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:78) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:441) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]

12:41:13,080 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/tc]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception starting filter DynamicResourceCompressionFilter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.teamcenter.presentation.appframework.log.Log
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.appframework.log.LogFactory.getLog(Unknown Source) [tcappframework.jar:]
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.appframework.log.LogFactory.getPkgLog(Unknown Source) [tcappframework.jar:]
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.gateway.filters.CompressionFilter.<clinit>(Unknown Source) [tcgateway.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ValueManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ValueManagedReferenceFactory.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:90) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$1.<init>(WebComponentInstantiator.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator.getReference(WebComponentInstantiator.java:55) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.instantiate(WebInjectionContainer.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:78) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:441) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]

12:41:13,137 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/tc]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception starting filter StaticResourceCompressionFilter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.teamcenter.presentation.gateway.filters.CompressionFilter
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ValueManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ValueManagedReferenceFactory.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:90) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$1.<init>(WebComponentInstantiator.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator.getReference(WebComponentInstantiator.java:55) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.instantiate(WebInjectionContainer.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:78) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:441) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]

12:41:13,178 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/tc]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception starting filter WebClientResponseTime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.teamcenter.presentation.gateway.filters.ResponseTimeFilter
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ValueManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ValueManagedReferenceFactory.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:90) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$1.<init>(WebComponentInstantiator.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator.getReference(WebComponentInstantiator.java:55) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.instantiate(WebInjectionContainer.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:78) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:441) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]

12:41:13,224 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error filterStart
12:41:13,226 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/tc] startup failed due to previous errors
12:41:13,248 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./tc: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./tc: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]

12:41:25,170 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.ra.deployer."tc.ear#JETIAdapter": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ra.deployer."tc.ear#JETIAdapter": JBAS010446: Failed to start RA deployment [tc.ear#JETIAdapter]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.metadata.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:103)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: IJ020056: Deployment failed: file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final_NEW/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment9561757203828c9b/JETIAdapter.rar-eb380c967a861d4c/contents/
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:2186)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1034)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.metadata.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService$AS7RaDeployer.doDeploy(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:173)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.metadata.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:100)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.teamcenter.mld.jmx.PlmSimpleMBeanFactory.<clinit>(PlmSimpleMBeanFactory.java:168)
    at com.teamcenter.mld.logging.Log.<init>(Log.java:848)
    at com.teamcenter.mld.logging.Log.<clinit>(Log.java:173)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.util.LogFactory.getLog(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.resourceadapter.spi.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.resourceadapter.spi.impl.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnectionFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1929)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: javax.management.JMRuntimeException: Failed to load MBeanServerBuilder class org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder from [Module "deployment.tc.ear.JETIAdapter.rar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.checkMBeanServerBuilder(MBeanServerFactory.java:503) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.getNewMBeanServerBuilder(MBeanServerFactory.java:539) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.newMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:316) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:231) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at com.teamcenter.mld.jmx.PlmLocalMBeanServer.getMBS(PlmLocalMBeanServer.java:396)
    at com.teamcenter.mld.jmx.PlmLocalMBeanServer.<clinit>(PlmLocalMBeanServer.java:89)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder from [Module "deployment.tc.ear.JETIAdapter.rar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.loadBuilderClass(MBeanServerFactory.java:446) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.checkMBeanServerBuilder(MBeanServerFactory.java:488) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stacktrace I can say that it is related to "teamcenter":

> 12:41:12,546 INFO [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1)
>   2016/02/11-07:11:12,546 UTC MLD Log init: **com.teamcenter.mld**
>   version V10000.1.0.20130604.00 (20130604)
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder from [Module
>   **"deployment.tc.ear.JETIAdapter.rar:main"** from Service Module Loader] at

Whatever this teamcenter is it looks like it was not correctly deployed.
I guess you need to get back to the "teamcenter deployment" document if such thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

please execute these steps:

1.Expand the configuration  directory:

```
jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration
```

2.Open the **standalone.xml**  file.

3.Change the HTTPS protocol to ALL . (The default protocol is TLSv1 .) Locate the subsystem  element for the urn:jboss:domain  subsystem, and add the following connector  element content:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
<connector name="https" scheme="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket
-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true"> 
         <ssl name="jbossSSL-SSL" password="private" protocol="ALL" key-
         alias="jbossSSL" certificate-key-file="D:\ssl\jbossSSL.keystore" />
</connector> </subsystem>
```

4.Locate the subsystem  element for the urn:jboss:domain  subsystem, and add the following global-modules  element content:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
   <global-modules>
      <module name="org.jboss.as.jmx" slot="main"/>
    </global-modules>
 </subsystem>
```

Locate the deployment-scanner  element and add the deployment-timeout  attribute with a value of 600  as follows:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
    <deployment-scanner path="deployments" 
                        relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" 
                        scan-interval="5000" 
                        deployment-timeout="600" />
</subsystem>
```